# Create 301 redirect that excludes facebook

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have a website that I changed from http to https. It has a 301 redirect to make sure everyone goes to the https version.

Unfortunately, that causes Facebook to see it as a different website and reset the share count to zero. In Facebook's developer guide, [they give a solution to this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#moving-urls):

> if your new URL was "https ://example.com/new-url", and the old URL was
>   https://example.com/old-url, you should include this snippit in the
>   new-url:
>
> meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/old-url" /

HOWEVER, the fact that I have a 301 redirect on the site makes this not work. Facebook's crawler never reaches the http site. Here's what Facebook says about that:

> If you want other clients to redirect when they visit the URL, you
>   must send your 301 HTTP response to all non-Facebook crawler clients.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that? I can edit my .htaccess file. But what I can I put in there that would accomplish this?

Thank you!

EDIT: My current .htaccess file is simply:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What are your current .htaccess rules? Add them to the question

Comment: Thanks. I believe I have added that to the end of the post now.

Comment: let me know how that answer works out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It says you need to prevent the crawler/user agent from redirecting. So just add it to the rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Facebot|facebookexternalhit/1.1) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So if https is *not* on and it's *not* the facebook crawler then redirect to https otherwise it will stay http.

Info here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler#updating

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why change "off" to "!^on" (not on)?

Comment: It will work either way. I just prefer it that way. It helps me when I'm adding conditions together, if **not** then ... etc.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the answer from Panama Jack here comes my version for nginx

```
location / { 
    if ($http_user_agent !~ "(Facebot|facebookexternalhit/1.1)") {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host$request_uri redirect;
    }
}
```